# Почему не срабатывает вставка HTML блока?

Tags: javascript

```
...onlick="func(this)"

func(th){
  var item = $(th).closest('.item');
  $('#block').append(item);
}
```

Не вставляется блок `item` в блок `#block`

По-прежнему не вставляется блок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вас устраивает перемещение элемента из одного места в другое в DOM по клику на него, то добавьте букву `c` в `onlick` и `function` к функции:

```
onclick="func(this)"

function func(th){
  var item = th;
  $('#block').append(item);
}
```

А если вам нужно создать копию объекта в нужном блоке, то можно написать так:

```
function func(th){
  var item = th.outerHTML;
  $('#block').append(item);
}
```

**UPD.**
Всё написанное выше работает и для блока с текстом:

[Пример 1. Блок при клике переносится в нужный блок и меняет своё положение в DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/rjegdtn7/1/)

[Пример 2. Блок при клике копируется в нужный блок, в DOM он также остаётся](http://jsfiddle.net/rjegdtn7/2/)

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Обновил ответ, в принципе, просто добавил примеры :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, почитайте про "[The evolution of events][1]" и живите сегодняшним днём, а не "дедушкиными" методами ;)

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript#The_evolution_of_events

Comment: @Deonis, поверьте, если бы это писал я, то всё было бы на jQuery :) а в данном случае был ответ на вопрос автора и он спросил: "Почему не работает такой код", а не "Как мне лучше реализовать этот функционал". Ведь проект для этого и существует, чтобы люди научились писать свой код, а не чтобы за них писали код другие